# Passenger Apache2 CentOS RVM Permission denied on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, centos, rvm, passenger

I've been following a few tutorials online trying to set up my rails application.
It looks like there's a permission configuration and I've tried to fix it without any luck.

I'm using Ruby 2.3.0.
I have a user called deploy (that does the Capistrano tasks) and another sudoer jwang. I installed rvm as a multi-user installation even through both users.

This is the error in the log:

```
App 1780 stderr: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: line 35:  /home/deploy/.rvm/scripts/rvm: Permission denied
App 1780 stderr: /bin/bash: /home/deploy/.bash_profile: Permission denied
App 1780 stdout: 
App 1780 stderr: *** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby: Permission denied (13)
```

This is my current configuration file for my site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName creste.ca

# Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's 'public' directory is
DocumentRoot /var/www/creste/current/public

PassengerRuby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby

# Relax Apache security settings
<Directory /var/www/creste/current/public>
  Allow from all
  Options -MultiViews
  # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Any insight would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: What command, causes the error?

Comment: When I try to start the server using sudo systemctl restart httpd and I view the page from my browser, it tells me to view the logs.

Answer (score 0):

SELinux problem... install rvm as sudo user...

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) then read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This is more of a comment. In order to comment, you need to earn more privileges. Until then, please answer only question with an actual **solution** to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem with you before and this is how i solve it:

try use set config PassengerUser https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengeruser . Set it with user that you use when install rvm.
Because you put the rails app on `/var/www/` which is that is owned with apache/www-data you need specify user that owned the rvm.

So, based on you example, just add:
`PassengerUser deploy`
after or before `PassengerRuby` config on your apache config.

Don't forget to restart the apache. 
Good luck.